# Unable to use window.history.replaceState function in Mail Addin

Tags: office-js

I have created a SPA mail add-in for outlook365 using durandal framework and using Office365 JavaScript API(office.js). Somewhere in my application I want to use 
`window.history.replaceState` function but this function is set explicitly null in office.js causing the error.

```
//following lines are presents in Office.js
window.history.replaceState = null;
window.history.pushState = null;
```

Answer (score 8):

I found a simple solution, `react-router` works fine after this change. We can backup the functions before `Office.js` nullifies them in `index.html`, and then restore:

```html
<script>
  window.backupHistoryFunctions = {};
  window.backupHistoryFunctions.pushState = window.history.pushState;
  window.backupHistoryFunctions.replaceState = window.history.replaceState;
</script>
<!-- Office JavaScript API -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js">
</script>
<script>      
  window.history.pushState = window.backupHistoryFunctions.pushState;
  window.history.replaceState = window.backupHistoryFunctions.replaceState;
  console.log(window.history.replaceState)
</script>
```

As the Microsoft rep notes, this would be incompatible with Excel, but I guess it'd be fine for a mail add-in.

Comment: Sorcery code, basically.

Comment: This solution works in Angular 16 with msal-angular 3.0.0, although you should call delete window.backupHistoryFunctions after you have restored from the object

Answer (score 2):

I have overridden this behaviour by doing the following

```
<script>
  var pushStateRef = history.pushState;
  var replaceStateRef = history.replaceState;
</script>
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  history.pushState = pushStateRef;
  history.replaceState = replaceStateRef;
  delete pushStateRef;
  delete replaceStateRef;
</script>
```

Assuming you only support browsers that support history, this should undo the Office.js nullifying.

I have also opened an issue @ Office.js repository:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/429

Comment: This worked for me in angular @microsoft fix his by enabling us to define where we want our plugin to be run. You have finally adopted chromium stop support for legacy or give us option where we want our plugin to be run

Answer (score 1):

There are certain functions that Microsoft doesn't support within Office Add Ins (Alert being another one). Certainly looks like they've deliberately disabled that one.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42703406/678505 for a related question (and answer) explaining why this particular functionality was disabled

Answer (score 1):

This code will work too:

```js
delete history.pushState;
delete history.replaceState;
```

Since `pushState()` and `replaceState` are available from prototype

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react-router with office.js, you will get "windows.history .pushState is not a function" error and all routes fails. what you can do is to add following code at bottom of html page to fall back to window.location.hash:

```
if (typeof(window.history.pushState) !== 'function') {
    window.history.pushState = function(path){
       window.location.hash = '#!' + path;
    }
}
```

post this in case of someone run into same issue.

Comment: Also please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42703406/678505 for a related question (and answer)

Answer (score 0):

in the Main HTML file (index.html or taskpane.html)

set this script code

```
  <script>
  
  let replaceState = window.history.replaceState;
  let pushState = window.history.pushState;
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.onload = function () {
    Office.onReady().then(() => {
      console.log("Office is ready!");
      window.history.replaceState = replaceState;
      window.history.pushState = pushState;
    });
  };
  script.src = "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js";
  head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

this late load is required due to bug in office-js causing a routing loop