# Office.initialize raises $rootScope:infdig

Tags: angularjs, ms-office, office-js, html5-history, office-app

Previously my add-in worked well in different browsers. Recently, in some browsers it does not load well (error messages in the console + just shows a blank page in UI); in some browsers it loads, but with error messages in the console. It is also odd that it works well in `localhost`, but not in production. Here is the minimum code:

```
console.log("OfficeHelpers.Utilities.host: " + OfficeHelpers.Utilities.host);
console.log("OfficeHelpers.Utilities.platform: " + OfficeHelpers.Utilities.platform);

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']) // it is important to not write 'ng-app="test"' in index.html, otherwise controller will be executed twice
        console.log("bootstrapped inside Office.initialize!");
    })
}

test = angular.module('test', ['ui.router']);
test.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('addinHomePlus', {
            url: '/addin/homePlus',
            template: 'testtest!!!'
        })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

In Chrome, it shows a blank page in UI and here are error messages with [$rootScope:infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D):

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong?

**Edit 1:** I use `https://cdn.rawgit.com/devote/HTML5-History-API/master/history.js` to help html5 mode. If I set `$rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(3)`, I got the following message for `$rootScope:infdig`:

```
3 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [null,[{"msg":"fn: function (){var a=jb(c.url()),b=jb(l.absUrl()),f=c.state(),g=l.$$replace,m=a!==b||l.$$html5&&e.history&&f!==l.$$state;if(q||m)q=!1,d.$evalAsync(function(){var b=l.absUrl(),c=d.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",b,a,l.$$state,f).defaultPrevented;l.absUrl()===b&&(c?(l.$$parse(a),l.$$state=f):(m&&h(b,g,f===l.$$state?null:l.$$state),\nk(a,f)))});l.$$replace=!1}"},{"msg":"fn: function (){return d.hash()}","newVal":""}]]
```

Comment: Can the template have !!! at the end?

Comment: I don't think `template: 'testtest!!!'` has problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't use `https://cdn.rawgit.com/devote/HTML5-History-API/master/history.js`, this `$rootScope:infdig` will disappear. But I do need `history.js` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703406/702977).