# Office.js Dialog Box Path Using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, office-js

I am using the `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` method in Office.js to create a popup that allows the user to login.

I used the yeoman generator to create a React template for the Add-in. I could not find an Auth0 example using Office.js and React, so I used this example which does not use react: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Auth0

To display the dialog box I pass the `displayDialogAsync` method a url that looks like: https://localhost:3000/src/taskpane/popup.html.

The react way I thought of would be creating a react compoennt for the popup and then using react router (Hash router not Browser Router [How to configure Office-js excel react add-in to use react-router-dom or alternative solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071999/how-to-configure-office-js-excel-react-add-in-to-use-react-router-dom-or-alterna)) to make the component accessible at `{taskpane endpoint}/popup` like on a website.

The addin locally runs at https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html so I tried to pass the url https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html/#popup but the popup is not routed to my component like it would on a normal react website. Instead I get a 404 error.

My question is do I need to add some additional configuration for this to work, or is it just not possible in Office.js.

Comment: Hash router would require you to use the # character. Have you tried navigating to `{taskpaneendpoint}/#popup` ? You should also share what your <Router> looks like

Comment: Hi Mavi, yes I have tried that but it did not work. Let me update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft recommends that you not pass a route to the `displayDialogAsync` method. See this best practice: [Best practices for using the Office Dialog API in an SPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-best-practices#best-practices-for-using-the-office-dialog-api-in-an-spa).