# Upgrade to Angular 16 break Sharepoint Ads in : this._history.replaceState is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, office-js, office-addins, angular16

I was upgrading my angular apps which run inside the Share Point office adds in. Currently angular app is using version 14, after I upgrade to angular 15 it works fine. But as soon as I upgrade to 16, I get below error.

```
TypeError: this._history.replaceState is not a function
```

This happens when calling

```
 this.router.navigate(['/path_to_component']);
```

I found a fix on this SO post. [Office.js nullifies browser history functions breaking history usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642863/office-js-nullifies-browser-history-functions-breaking-history-usage)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Office js deletes window.history.pushState and window.history.replaceState. Cache them and restore them
    window._historyCache = {
        replaceState: window.history.replaceState,
        pushState: window.history.pushState
    };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Office js deletes window.history.pushState and window.history.replaceState. Restore them
    window.history.replaceState = window._historyCache.replaceState;
    window.history.pushState = window._historyCache.pushState;
</script>
```

I am not sure how this is breaking only after upgrade to Angular 16 though its relate to office.js

I am using the same version of office.js.

I have already use hash location strategy. Could any one help me to understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at Angular 14/15's source code, we can see that `BrowserPlatformLocation` contains this method:

```js
override replaceState(state: any, title: string, url: string): void {
    if (supportsState()) {
      this._history.replaceState(state, title, url);
    } else {
      this.location.hash = url;
    }
  }
```

Sources:

1. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14.0.x/packages/common/src/location/platform_location.ts#L180C3-L186C4 (Angular 14)
2. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/15.0.x/packages/common/src/location/platform_location.ts#L180C3-L186C4 (Angular 15)

What you should notice is `supportsState()`:

```js
export function supportsState(): boolean {
  return !!window.history.pushState;
}
```

In Angular 14/15 there's a fallback case if `pushState` is not available, so you code works well and also `this._history.replaceState()` works correctly.

From Angular 16, that check was removed:

```js
override replaceState(state: any, title: string, url: string): void {
    this._history.replaceState(state, title, url);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/16.0.x/packages/common/src/location/platform_location.ts#L165

So, because `office.js` removes `pushState` and `replaceState` and there's no fallback case, your code breaks (until you use the fix you already found).

Comment: I do not know what the "already found" fox is, can you please add a link?

Comment: I'm sorry, i just noticed that I typed"fox" for some reason, I meant "solution" it wouldn't let me edit it.

Comment: Hi, if you're referring to my sentence "until you use the fix you already found", i was referring to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642863/office-js-nullifies-browser-history-functions-breaking-history-usage

Comment: I added an issue to Angular, not sure if it will ever get any attention: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/54420